# Let user change deployed taskbar pins in win10

Tags: windows-10

I'm working on a Windows 10 deployment and want to use a LayoutModification.xml to [configure the taskbar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar). The deployment works perfectly and makes my changes but users aren't able to remove these pinned items when they are unneeded. How do I allow this?

```
<LayoutModificationTemplate
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"
    xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout"
    xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout"
    xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout"
    Version="1">
....  
   <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection PinListPlacement="Replace" >
      <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
        <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
          <taskbar:UWA AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" />
          <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\File Explorer.lnk" />
          <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\xxxxlnk" />

        </taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
      </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
   </CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>


</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

**EDITS:**

This is occurring on Win10 1703.

I was thinking it might just be some NTFS rights, but with using the new profile deployment method this LayoutModification.xml file is copied from the default user to the local user profile only on creation. Within the standard user profile (with standard user rights) if I edit the pinned item on their copy of LayoutModification.xml it disappears. It's a workaround but not really a fix.

Comment: I had some success in removing the default pins in 1511, but they are really going out of their way to block removing them in later builds. What build are you running?

Comment: @CoryKnutson 1703.

Comment: Can it be a directory right to give to your user ? from memory those pin for alluser are in the alluser folder, thus only local admin can remove them. (As I dont think the deployment move the .lnk to the user store)

Comment: @yagmoth555 I had the same thought overnight. We're deploying via the default profile method so it's a file owned and editable by the standard user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked back at this several times over the last year and came to the conclusion it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

try with this script after applying the layout :

```powershell
$regAliases = @("HKLM", "HKCU")

#Assign the start layout and force it to apply with "LockedStartLayout" at both the machine and user level

foreach ($regAlias in $regAliases){
    $basePath = $regAlias + ":\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows"
    $keyPath = $basePath + "\Explorer" 
    IF(!(Test-Path -Path $keyPath)) { 
        New-Item -Path $basePath -Name "Explorer"
    }
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $keyPath -Name "LockedStartLayout" -Value 1
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $keyPath -Name "StartLayoutFile" -Value "C:\Windows\StartLayout.xml"
}

#Restart Explorer, open the start menu (necessary to load the new layout), and give it a few seconds to process

Stop-Process -name explorer
Start-Sleep -s 5
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('^{ESCAPE}')
Start-Sleep -s 5

#Enable the ability to pin items again by disabling "LockedStartLayout"

foreach ($regAlias in $regAliases){
    $basePath = $regAlias + ":\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows"
    $keyPath = $basePath + "\Explorer" 
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $keyPath -Name "LockedStartLayout" -Value 0
}

#Restart Explorer and delete the layout file

Stop-Process -name explorer
```